# SQL Server Query (Combining Two rows into one)

Tags: sql-server

I have data in following format in SQL Server database.

| SearchID | Text1 | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Search1 | Black | NULL |
| Search1 | NULL | Hammer |
| Search2 | Telephone | NULL |
| Search2 | NULL | Marker |

I need data in following format.

| SearchID | Text1 | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Search1 | Black | Hammer |
| Search2 | Telephone | Marker |

Since text1 and text2 could have any random text, I couldn't use pivot. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Are there only ever 2 rows that you want to combine?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @SteveFord: I did try group by, but just realized I was adding more columns to group by than needed and yes, I have multiple rows, but only two columns that I wanted to combine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `max` and `group by`. Something like

```
SELECT
 searchid, max(text1), max(text)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY searchid
```

This works with your sample data, where there is one non-null `text` and one non-null `text1` per `searchid` that you care about.

Comment: Thank you! I was already doing group by, but I had one more column in group by and that didn't help. Thank you so much!